Brackets of bNiceArray do not behave as expected when first-row option is used

In the figure above the brackets should extend along with the contents
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{c |c}[first-row,first-col,c,margin]
        & n - 1
        & (n - 1) - n_{v}
        \rlap{\vrule width 0.0pt depth 1ex height 0em}
        \\
        n - 1
        & A
        & B
        \rlap{\vrule width 0.1pt depth 0ex height 4em}
        \\
        \hline
        (n - 1) - n_{v}
        & C
        & D
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}


You are right. That seems to be a bug. I will investigate.

I have corrected that bug (see the depot nicematrix on GitHub).
It will be in the next version of nicematrix on CTAN.

This bug is corrected in the version 7.0a 2024-12-16 available on CTAN.
